# List of countries for USPS API

Tags: api, usps

I'm going to use the USPS API for international shipping rates, but the list they provide is nearly 500 countries long.  The listings include:

```
Fernando Po (Equatorial Guinea)
Hashemite Kingdom (Jordan) 
Muscat (Oman)
Nauru
Negri Sembilan (Malaysia)
```

And they all work as listed to provide postal rates.

But the list seems REALLY long.

I wondered if anyone had any suggestions about a shorter list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually once went through that "list" (those tons of pages) manually, removed duplicates, renamed references, etc. and correlated them with ISO codes for a shipping cache Java application I wrote recently. I never finished it; I ended up not using it in the end.

I found a much easier way to get their list was to start from the other end: just steal it from USPS itself. Go to their [international rate calculator](http://ircalc.usps.gov/) and view the source for the select box. A couple regular expressions should then have you on your way. It may not be completely up-to-date, I wouldn't be surprised if another department or different people maintained the two lists, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: If anyone who stumbles across this needs to do the same thing, I've created a Python script to parse out the country list from the website: https://github.com/tajmorton/extract_usps_countries/blob/master/extract_countries.py

Comment: I tried this, but some countries are returning errors for shipping calculation